# Linux Storage growth

Tags: linux, shell, awk, directory, storage

/mnt/storage/test

Have a size of 3 TB and usage is 403Gb and available is 2.4T

the storage gets an increase on a daily basis. is there a way where I can know how much it is growing for a certain time of period? displaying the date as well?
for example, I would like to know how much of size that storage got increase for the past 7 days displaying the dates(monday:100MB ; Tusday:200MB..)

Comment: The system do not save such information, if that was the question. Or you are asking how to do a script to store daily usage values? In that case, write down your ideas (and what did you tried)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to do it with some awk and find. The problem is that it is a bit slow:

**1. Get all useful information with find:**

Useful information is *inode number*, to keep track of hardlinked files, *disk-usage* for sparse files and keeping track of the used space and last modification time in epoch. The following command would read:

```
$ find /mnt/storage/test -type f -printf "%i %TF %k %s\n"
```

This will output the inode number, the modification time, the disk-usage in 1kb blocks, and the byte-size of the file.

**2. Process the data with some awesome awk:**

```
$ find /mnt/storage/test -type f -printf "%i %TF %k %s\n"     \
   | awk -v ref="$(date -d "7 days ago" "+%F")"               \
          'a[$1]++ { next }
           ($2 >= ref) { b[$2]+=$3; c[$3]+=$4 }
           END { for(i in b) print i, b[i], c[i] }' | sort
```

which will output something like:

```
2020-07-15 49931 139268446
2020-07-16 46071 129526625
2020-07-17 51385 143423680
2020-07-18 46723 130799790
2020-07-19 39836 111916417
2020-07-20 51114 143329960
2020-07-21 47159 132018961
2020-07-22 107435 683987291
```

Here you can now see that on day 2020-07-15 we generated files which occupy 49931kb on disk. All files combined contain 139268446 bytes of data. I have output both columns here just to show that bytes-size and disk-usage are two different things. It is possible that files occupy larger amount of diskspace (sparse files) or less (compressed file system).

**note:** if a file is generated on day *x* and modified on day *y*, it's full size will be counted to day *y* and will not be part of day *x*.